# How to tag song artist in a YouTube video?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I've published a number of songs to YouTube.  Recently, I tried the YouTube Music app.

When I've searched for my artist name, I've noticed that it comes up, but the only songs listed under the artist are for songs I've published via CD Baby.

I would like to list other songs under the artist, but I can find no way to do this, either through the API or through the web interface.

How do I tag my videos as belonging to the YouTube Music artist?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert a tag in a video, then the [`Videos: insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) can help you with that.

You can set values for these [lists of properties](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#request-body):

- `snippet.title`
- `snippet.description`
- **`snippet.tags[]`**
- `snippet.categoryId`

Just check this [example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#examples) for different language on how to do that.

Here is an example of tags result, so if you search in the YouTube video using one of this tags as your search parameter, this video will be part on the search result.

[image]

Comment: It's not just search results though—in the YouTube Music app, they categorize songs by artist, with generic search results shown below.  Are there specific tags that associate a video with an artist?